# SaltStack: multiple host and almost the same conf files. Need advice

Tags: salt-stack

I have one salt-master server and ~40 Zabbix proxy servers with salt-minions.

I want to manage configuration files of Zabbix proxy servers. Zabbix conf files are the same except Hostname, Timeout settings and PSK Identity.

Do I need different sls files for all 40 hosts? Or there is some tricks how to manage environment like this?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

- 1 sls file which containing the states to manage configuration files ;
- configuration files including Jinja labels, e.g. *{{ Hostname }}* ;
- minion / zabbix-proxy settings in per-minion *pillars* or *grains*.

But several formulas already exist, like [zabbix-formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/zabbix-formula), and they might fit your needs.

Best regards,